# Servicestack facebook auth via mobile

Tags: servicestack

I've read through every resource our there on the servicestack wiki, examples on github, forums and stackoverflow to figure out implementing facebook integration with a mobile app and servicestack backend. However, none of them have the answer or I'm missing something basic.

In our workflow, a user decides to Register on through the mobile app using Facebook:

- We contact Facebook requesting permissions to the user's account
- User grants permissions (let's not worry about denied for now)
- We get a user access token and everything is good so far

Next, we want to access our ServiceStack backend (using the Facebook Auth Provider) to create an account and automatically log the user in the first time. The examples refer to the method where a web browser is used. What if I want to pass the user auth token from my mobile app to the server to fetch the user permissions and create an account if it doesn't exist and then log the user in?

The existing endpoint seems to work only for a browser app because it also does a redirect. We need a way to pass in the user auth token and log the user in (or create an account if it doesn't exist). Any idea how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 1):

To login via OAuth in Mobile Apps, you'd typically launch a browser control to have it redirect to the remote OAuth site where it gets the users permission and captures their credentials just as it would with a website.

If you're developing a Mobile App using Xamarin the [TechStacksAuth](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacksAuth) shows an example on how you can use Xamarin.Auth control to authenticate with a ServiceStack back-end via OAuth.

Comment: The problem with using a browser control is that users might have to enter their facebook credentials again if it isn't saved in their keychain / cache. In order to use the facebook creds from the installed app and send the token to the backend, I might have to create a custom authenticator...unless there's a way to do that using the servicestack facebook auth?

Comment: @theoutlander it doesn't support that, but the [FacebookAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Auth/FacebookAuthProvider.cs) is fairly simple so should be possible to modify it to create a custom provider that accepts tokens directly.